# Why XORing two hex strings produce an output in the following format: '\x02\x07\x01P\x00\x07

Tags: python, xor

The ultimate purpose of this program is to get the words  Eve and Bob back in plain text from XORed hex strings. So first I got Eve and bob in hex, then XORed them together, was hoping to then see the result in hex.The problem is when I XOR the hex strings for Bob and Eve I get this notation, '\x02\x07\x01P\x00\x07 and as a beginner I have no idea what this means. what is that notation?

The plan is to later work my way backwards from the XORed Eve and Bob and get each name in plain text separately.

My simple code so far is:

```
    a= 'bob'
    b='Eve'
    g=a.encode("hex")
    v=b.encode("hex")

    def strxor(a, b):
     if len(a) > len(b):
      return "".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a[:len(b)], b)])     
     else:
      return "".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a, b[:len(a)])])
    k=strxor(g,v)
```

Comment: `\x` means the following "digits" are in base 16 (hexadecimal).

Comment: `"\x##"` represents a single byte ... it is always followed by exactly 2 digits ...

Answer (score 0):

this is basic xor_encryption... in effect b works like an encryption/decryption key

```
import itertools
name1 = "eve online"
name2 = "bob"

xor_encrypted = "".join(chr(ord(a)^ord(b)) for a,b in zip(name1,itertools.cycle(name2)))

print repr(xor_encrypted) # 3 characters will look something like '\x07\x19\x07'

xor_decrypted = "".join(chr(ord(a)^ord(b)) for a,b in zip(xor_encrypted,itertools.cycle(name2)))

print repr(xor_decrypted) # should now print our decrypted 'eve'
```